# Google Maps - Calculate route length between 3 points

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have simple script to calculate distance between two places. I have 2 input with autocomplete. It work's like I want but I need to add one more thing. So, let's say I have point B and C. My script will calculate route between them, but I want to add another static point which is A (I know coordinates for it). So, I need to calculate distance between A and B, then between B and C and add result. Simple example

```
A -> B = distance 20km
B -> C = distance 130km
total = 150
```

Below is my code.

```js
$(function() {
  // add input listeners
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var from_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('from_places'));
    var to_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('to_places'));

    google.maps.event.addListener(from_places, 'place_changed', function() {
      var from_place = from_places.getPlace();
      var from_address = from_place.formatted_address;
      $('#origin').val(from_address);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(to_places, 'place_changed', function() {
      var to_place = to_places.getPlace();
      var to_address = to_place.formatted_address;
      $('#destination').val(to_address);
    });

  });
  // calculate distance
  function calculateDistance() {
    var origin = $('#origin').val();
    var destination = $('#destination').val();
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      // unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL, // miles and feet.
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.metric, // kilometers and meters.
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
  }
  // get distance results
  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      $('#result').html(err);
    } else {
      var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
      var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
      if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        $('#result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between " + origin + " and " + destination);
      } else {
        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
        console.log(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
        var distance_in_kilo = distance.value / 1000; // the kilom
        var distance_in_mile = distance.value / 1609.34; // the mile
        var duration_text = duration.text;
        var duration_value = duration.value;
        var total_cost = distance_in_kilo * 3.44;
        // $('#in_mile').text(distance_in_mile.toFixed(2));
        $('#in_kilo').text(distance_in_kilo.toFixed(2) + ' km');
        // $('#duration_text').text(duration_text);
        // $('#duration_value').text(duration_value);
        $('#from').text(origin);
        $('#to').text(destination);
        $('#cost').text(total_cost.toFixed(2) + ' zł');
      }
    }
  }
  // print results on submit the form
  $('#distance_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculateDistance();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=pl" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form id="distance_form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Origin: </label>
            <input id="from_places" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a location" />
            <input id="origin" type="hidden" name="origin" required/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Destination: </label>
            <input id="to_places" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a location" />
            <input id="destination" type="hidden" name="destination" required/>
          </div>

          <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="result">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <!-- <li  class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                Distance In Mile :
                                <span id="in_mile" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
                            </li> -->
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              Distance is Kilo:
              <span id='in_kilo' class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
            </li>
            <!-- <li  class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                IN TEXT:
                                <span id="duration_text" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
                            </li>
                            <li  class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                IN MINUTES:
                                <span id="duration_value" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
                            </li> -->

            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              FROM:
              <span id="from" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              TO:
              <span id="to" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              COST:
              <span id="cost" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don’t know how to add static point to my code. I tried to add point to origins array and destinations too but it didn’t calculate proper

Comment: Could you not just make two calls to the Distance Matrix service, with call #1 being pointA to pointB, then call #2 being pointB to pointC?

Comment: Yes, it is a solution. But is it good practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding waypoints to Google Distance Matrix to determine mileage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702077/adding-waypoints-to-google-distance-matrix-to-determine-mileage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put both origins in the origin array, put both destinations in the destination array.

```
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
    origins: [A, B],
    destinations: [B, C],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.metric, // kilometers and meters.
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
}, callback);
```