# how to pass multiple path points in google distance matrix api using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-distancematrix-api

Hello I want to pass multiple path points in google distance matrix API

Currently i am passing this

```
 "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins="+originsLatLong+"&destinations="+destinationLatLong;
            url = url+"&key="+googleMapKey;
```

But I and to pass multiple path points

Like this api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=600x600&maptype=roadmap&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|26.8415368,75.804844|26.842256703993666,75.80808773014743|26.844134194244713,75.80782017832321|26.84816416862642,75.80965364469634|26.851396259886187,75.81109081772398|26.854319586816906,75.80928677934519|26.855176261161244,75.80702835940984&markers=26.8415368,75.804844|26.855176261161244,75.80702835940984&key=KEY
```

Comment: Refer this official Documentation: [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#required-parameters)

Comment: @ShivajiMutkule in the document there is no option to pass multiple coordinates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28702411/4365927